# Prove the therem of function f that is differentiable at only one point

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f$ be $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$. I understand and I saw function as $f(x)=x^2g(x)$ that can show that a function can be differentiable at one point. If  such $x0$ exists is differentiable at this point then:
$\lim_{x \to x0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}  {\Delta x}  = f'(x0)$

how can I prove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $f(x)=x^2 g(x)$, you have $f(0) = 0$. Then

$$\left\vert \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \right\vert \le \vert x \vert \vert g(x) \vert.$$

So at least if $g$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$ this proves that $f^\prime(0) = 0$ as $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x g(x)=0$.

Comment: so i can say that it works for every $x0$ that i chose ?

Comment: No that works for $x_0=0$, but can be wrong for $x_0 \neq 0$ if $g$ has not sufficient properties. Take for example for $g$ the map equal to $0$ on rational numbers and to $1$ elsewhere. Then $f$ is not continuous at any point except $0$.